# I can not reinstall MySQL because it keeps the old password

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I did the uninstallation of mysql with this comand:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but then I tried to reinstate it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

but when I launch `mysql_secure_installation`, he asks me for the password I do not have. and so I'm stuck

**Questions:**

How can I completely uninstall mysql?

How can I overcome this password problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mysql_secure_installation` is asking you for a password, it means you are not running it using `sudo`.

Just run it as:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

If it still asks for a password after a fresh install, press ENTER.

Comment: thanks, with sudo mysql_secure_installation it worked but now I have to run mysql with sudo es: sudo mysql -u root -p, how can I remove the sudo command from this action

Comment: Check this and make backups first! https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` configuration `datadir` defines where the databases are kept.  Normally it is `/var/lib/mysql`, inside there will most likely be the databases from the previous install.

The databases are saved as `${datadir}/${DATABASE}`.  The MySQL passwords are kept in the `mysql` database in the `user` table.  Save what you need and remove the entire `datadir` directory then try to install `mysql-server` again.

Comment: thanks for the help GracefulRestart, the path /var/lib/mysql does not exist, I think it was deleted with the uninstallation made today and I think the folder datadir has also been deleted, but I always have the same problem :(